# kendo-numerictextbox' is not a known element

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am getting error while trying to implement kendo-numerictextbox in angular 7 application. I am currently using kendo-dropdownlist and textbox controls without any issues. I am not sure what package is missing. Is there some dependency that I am missing

```
<kendo-numerictextbox [(ngModel)]="f.RedsNoticeDays" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;"></kendo-numerictextbox>
```

I am getting the following error and dont know the reason why

app.module

```
import { LayoutModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-layout';
import { DateInputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';
import { DropDownsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
import { InputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs';
import { TreeViewModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-treeview';
```

Error

```
'kendo-numerictextbox' is not a known element:
1. If 'kendo-numerictextbox' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'kendo-numerictextbox' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("ndoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.RedsNoticeDays" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;" /--> 
              [ERROR ->]<kendo-numerictextbox ></kendo-numerictextbox>
          </td>
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.6",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.15",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^3.5.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^3.4.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^2.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.6.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^3.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor": "3.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^2.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.5.8",
    "@progress/kendo-ui": "^2019.1.206",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.9",
    "acorn": "^6.0.5",
    "ag-grid-angular": "20.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "20.0.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "20.0.0",
    "angular-file-uploader": "^4.1.3",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^4.0.5",
    "modernizr": "^3.7.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
    "ngx-input-file": "^7.0.2",
    "ngx-spinner": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-treeview": "^6.0.1",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.54",
    "readable-stream": "2.2.6",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "sass": "^1.17.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "vendors": "^1.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "7.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/pdfmake": "^0.1.3",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "3.1.6"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on this [offical documantation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/numerictextbox/) has an stackblitz link. if you look at that example its only imported 
`import { InputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs';
import { LabelModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-label';`

these 2 modules at app.module.ts file to use kendo-numerictextbox.