# 'kendo-textbox' is not a known element

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I added this code from [telerik](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/textbox/readonly-state/) webside but I am getting errors. I also tried other solutions from stackoverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56283933/kendo-numerictextbox-is-not-a-known-element). My Angular version is 8.

```
<kendo-textbox></kendo-textbox>
```

I imported these modules

```
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { NumericTextBoxModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs';
import { InputsModule, TextBoxModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs';
import { DateInputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';
import { DropDownsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
import { WindowModule, DialogsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dialog';
import { TreeViewModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-treeview';
import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';
import { IconsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-icons';
import { LabelModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-label';
```

But I am getting this error -

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'kendo-textbox' is not a known element:
1. If 'kendo-textbox' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'kendo-textbox' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
            </div>
            <div class="p-col-12">
                [ERROR ->]<kendo-textbox></kendo-textbox>
                <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Employee "): ng:///Pickermodule/SingleEmployeePickerComponent.html@10:16
'kendo-textbox' is not a known element:
1. If 'kendo-textbox' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'kendo-textbox' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
            </div>
            <div class="p-col-12">
                [ERROR ->]<kendo-textbox></kendo-textbox>
                <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Employee "): ng:///Pickermodule/SingleEmployeePickerComponent.html@10:16
Error: Template parse errors:
'kendo-textbox' is not a known element:
1. If 'kendo-textbox' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'kendo-textbox' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
            </div>
            <div class="p-col-12">
                [ERROR ->]<kendo-textbox></kendo-textbox>
                <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Employee "): ng:///Pickermodule/SingleEmployeePickerComponent.html@10:16
'kendo-textbox' is not a known element:
1. If 'kendo-textbox' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'kendo-textbox' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
            </div>
            <div class="p-col-12">
                [ERROR ->]<kendo-textbox></kendo-textbox>
                <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Employee "): ng:///Pickermodule/SingleEmployeePickerComponent.html@10:16
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:11143)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25476)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25464)
    at compiler.js:25408
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:25408)
    at compiler.js:25321
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2166)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25320)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:30873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:469)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:454)
```

Other telerik components are working just fine.

Comment: This often happen when you dont import the module on the right place, or when the import is on a shared module, but not exported.